# How To Add A Separate Header In The Navbar

Tags: html, css, navbar, blogger

I would like some help in coding together the final element of my hovering navigation bar. Currently I have tab links on the left side of the navbar and on the right I have social media links and a search bar. Now I would like to add a "header" - an image of my blog name - in the middle. I have tried adding the img however although its in the html coding, it does not appear on the blog. A similar navbar can be viewed on http://www.mediamarmalade.com. I have included the html coding below :

```
<div id='headermiddle'>

<a href='http:www.blankesque.com'><img src='http://i1379.photobucket.com/albums/ah140/mynamesiram/Mobile%20Uploads/B447BE1A-FA19-4619-A844-65CBEA644DB1_zpsaj5p6y0d.gif'/></a>

</div>
```

And the CSS Coding is as follows :

```
#headermiddle a img {
width: 10px;
height: auto;
position: absolute;
text-align: center;
  }
```

The URL to my blog is as follows : http://www.blankesque.com

Comment: try to adjust the width to something like `600` pixels and double check the URL that is in the image tag, does it open a web page or an image? for me it opens up a html page. Make sure you are copying the correct url for the image source.

Comment: Thank you for you suggestion. It has indeed worked. However I'm unable to move the image towards the center. I have tried float:center and text-align:center but neither are working. I'd appreciate if you could help me with this issue also.

Comment: try this `#headermiddle a img { display: block; margin: 0 auto ;}` - let me know if this works. i can write an answer below and you can mark it as the correct answer :)

Answer (score 0):

I assume that (on the similar sample page) the image is placed in a seperate Tag - not in the header. You can see this if you shrink your browser window.

The nav and social buttons are aligned left/right sided.